# Rails keeping git versions correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I hope this is an ok question for StackOverflow.  If it isn't, let me know. Thanks!!

I have my first Rails app about to go production. I'm using GIT and Github for version control.  And I'm using CAP to deploy to our own servers.

We have one server for Staging and one for Production.

So, lets say it's day one of production.  And I'm also coding new features on my iMac.  So, I'm making changes and saving to GIT, Github and staging.

But, then the users run into a small error that I need to make a quick fix on production.

Well, I've already started making major changes to the code and I don't want to put that into production.

How would I make the quick fix the users need?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ill assume you have a `prod` branch and a `devel` branch, and the tip of prod is what has been released to prod.

You can;
1. `git stash` all  your current work if you havent committed it yet.
2. `git checkout prod`
3. Create a new branch for your hot fix, fix it, merge it back to `prod`  and release it.
4. `git checkout devel` and `git stash apply` your stash if you need to.
5. `git merge prod` into your `devel` branch so it has the hot fix you just deployed.

If you dont have separate branches for prod and devel, now might be a good time to set them up :)

See the section *6.3 Stashing* of the progit book.

http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: +1 and the hotfix should be merged to devel too, so that the next release won't have the same bug.

Comment: Do I establish the branches and do the checkout from Github?

Comment: I would branch locally and push to github... I don't use GitHub so don't know if you can create branches there directly.

Comment: Quick question - Step 3 - why create a hot fix branch?  Why not make hot fix to prod?

Comment: You *can* do that if you want. If you were the only developer, maybe thats simplest solution. However, I'd highly recommend setting up a branching strategy [like this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). It will scale very well as your project grows...  and if your project doesn't grow? Well at least you've learnt a scalable branching strategy for next time :)

Answer (score 0):

You may create a branch for fixies, fix a bug there, and update your application on production server with this branch. In some moment you will merge them (branches).